# understand this.each in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am learning how to write a jQuery plugin. I have this code below, my question is what does `this` stand for in the code below?

```
$.fn.myNewPlugin = function() {

    return this.each(function() {
        // Do something to each element here.
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a plugin you are extending the jQuery object, and because the jQuery object is a sequence, when you use `return this.each(function () { });` then your plugin is executed for each item of the sequence.